# Pyspark: How to create a nested Json by adding dynamic prefix to each column based on a row value

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark, nested, transformation

I have a dataframe in below format.

Input:

| id | Name_type | Name | Car |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | First | rob | Nissan |
| 2 | First | joe | Hyundai |
| 1 | Last | dent | Infiniti |
| 2 | Last | Kent | Genesis |

need to transform into a json column by appending a row value below format for a given key column  as shown below.

Result expected:

| id | json_column |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {"First_Name":"rob","First_*Car", "Nissan","Last_Name":"dent","Last_Car", "Infiniti"} |
| 2 | {"First_Name":"joe","First_Car", "Hyundai","Last_Name":"kent","Last_Car", "Genesis"} |

with below piece of code

```
column_set = ['Name','Car']
df = df.withColumn("json_data", to_json(struct(\[df\[x\] for x in column_set\])))
```

I was able to generate data as

| id | Name_type | Json_data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | First | {"Name":"rob", "Car": "Nissan"} |
| 2 | First | {"Name":"joe", "Car": "Hyundai"} |
| 1 | Last | {"Name":"dent", "Car": "infiniti"} |
| 2 | Last | {"Name":"kent", "Car": "Genesis"} |

I was able to create a json column using to_json for a given row.

But not able to figure out how to append the row value to a column name and convert to nested json for a given key column.

Answer (score 0):

To do what you want, you first need to manipulate your input dataframe a little bit. You can do this by grouping by the `id` column, and pivoting around the `Name_type` column like so:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import first

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        ("1", "First", "rob", "Nissan"),
        ("2", "First", "joe", "Hyundai"),
        ("1", "Last", "dent", "Infiniti"),
        ("2", "Last", "Kent", "Genesis")
    ],
    ["id", "Name_type", "Name", "Car"]
)
output = df.groupBy("id").pivot("Name_type").agg(first("Name").alias('Name'), first("Car").alias('Car'))

output.show()
+---+----------+---------+---------+--------+
| id|First_Name|First_Car|Last_Name|Last_Car|
+---+----------+---------+---------+--------+
|  1|       rob|   Nissan|     dent|Infiniti|
|  2|       joe|  Hyundai|     Kent| Genesis|
+---+----------+---------+---------+--------+
```

Then you can use the exact same code as what you used to get your wanted result, but using 4 columns instead of 2:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import to_json, struct

column_set = ['First_Name','First_Car', 'Last_Name', 'Last_Car']
output = output.withColumn("json_data", to_json(struct([output[x] for x in column_set])))

output.show(truncate=False)
+---+----------+---------+---------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|id |First_Name|First_Car|Last_Name|Last_Car|json_data                                                                         |
+---+----------+---------+---------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|1  |rob       |Nissan   |dent     |Infiniti|{"First_Name":"rob","First_Car":"Nissan","Last_Name":"dent","Last_Car":"Infiniti"}|
|2  |joe       |Hyundai  |Kent     |Genesis |{"First_Name":"joe","First_Car":"Hyundai","Last_Name":"Kent","Last_Car":"Genesis"}|
+---+----------+---------+---------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```